# WinJS write binary data / blob to file

Tags: cordova, windows-8, windows-8.1, winjs

Do WinJS or Windows 8 javascript apps in general support writing blobs to file? All the examples and documentation I have found only mention writing text. I need to store binary data within the application, not user defined via a file picker.

In case it does not, what's an alternative? Writing base64 strings?
Or better look into IndexedDB?

Comment: this link could help you https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT

Comment: Thanks! I think I probably better switch to IndexedDB plus a SqlLite shim, but still interested if blobs can be written in Win8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variety of techniques, but if you'd just like to write an array of bytes for example to the file system, you might use [`PathIO.WriteBytesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pathio.writebytesasync.aspx). Have a look at the other methods of [`PathIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pathio.aspx) for simple ways to access the file system.

IndexedDB may not be the best fit depending on the amount of data you need to store. There's a limit of 250MB per application for example.

Comment: There is no ReadBytesAsync, but fortunately XmlHttpRequest provides a byte array on downloading and does accept an array buffer on uploading.